# UITable view button.tag to get value of row

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am having Tableview which shows comments on facebook post. I am getting comments in Array and comments Id in second array ..I have taken one uibutton in tableview cell. on that button I want to get comment id of particular comment so that I can pass that id to like method..But It is always taking id Of last comment..How can I ID of comment on Button.tag property,, My code is :

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        return [[facebook comments] count];
    }


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

    like = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

        like.frame = CGRectMake(60, 70, 40, 20);

        [like setTitle:@"like" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [like setTag:indexPath.row];
        [like addTarget:self action:@selector(likeComment) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:like];

        ;


        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:10.0];

        cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12.0];

        cell.textLabel.text = [[facebook commentId]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    

        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[facebook comments]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSLog(@"%@ person like this",[facebook likesCount] );


        NSLog(@"%@ person like this comment",[facebook commentLikes]);



        return cell;
    }

    - (void )likeComment {

        NSString *idStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/likes",[[facebook commentId]objectAtIndex:like.tag]];



        [fbGraph doGraphPost:idStr withPostVars:nil];   

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"You like this"
                                                       message:@"" delegate:nil
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil ];

        [alert show];
        [alert release];




}
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, which you are facing because you are always using the **last** `like` **button**.

You require to make few changes, Append an in the function name like `likeComment:`.

```
    [like addTarget:self action:@selector(likeComment:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And modify your `likeComment` method like below.

```
- (void )likeComment:(id) sender {

        UIButton* myLikeButton = (UIButton*)sender;
        NSString *idStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/likes",[[facebook commentId]objectAtIndex:myLikeButton.tag]];



        [fbGraph doGraphPost:idStr withPostVars:nil];   

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"You like this"
                                                       message:@"" delegate:nil
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil ];

        [alert show];
        [alert release];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help ..I changed like.tag to MyLikeButton.tag

Comment: @Pallavi : Good , I miss to change that, Thanks

Comment: ok.have you used facebook graph api.Because I am not getting all comments, Its only showing few comments

Comment: @Pallavi :Still having issue ...?

Comment: My one post has 7 comments and iphone app is displaying only 3 comments. and the posts which I send from my app is displayed in my tableview while posts sent from facebook site is not visible in my app.why this is happening

Comment: And only my post and comments are visible..comments and post from other is not visible

Comment: It is showing number of comments count = 7 ,, But message=" " is only 3

Comment: Once you get the feeds from **facebook** call `reloadData` method of UITabelView.